# Sci-fi animated movie: ship in trouble, crashes into planet

Tags: story-identification

I'm hoping someone here will have an idea of the name of this movie I'm trying to find. It's a sci-fi full-length animated film. The opening scene has the viewer approaching a large spaceship from behind. Nothing particularly seems out of the ordinary . The camera then moves inside the ship to which the viewer can see this ship is in trouble has the occupant are running from explosions and debris falling. The camera continues to move through the ship and to the outside again where you are now looking at the front of the ship. The camera angle continues to pan out as the ship then crashes into a planet.
Any ideas from anyone as to what this movie might be? Also, I seem to recall it being a one word title. This movie would have come out about ten or so years ago. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Titan A.E starts similar if memory holds. Or is this anime?